# Calling a .py file on path from the OS command line

Tags: python, linux

I have written a script in Python 3 and have it stored in a Tools/ folder on path.  This file (called example.py in this post) reads in a local inputfile.yml.  I am able to find the file using:

```
which example.py
```

I have verified that python3 is installed and on path using:

```
which python3
```

I am now trying to run the following command from the linux command line:

```
python3 example.py inputfile.yml
```

I have also tried:

```
example.py inputfile.yml
```

How can I run a python script that is not local but is on path?

Comment: What happens when you try those commands?

Comment: When I call python3 example.py inputfile.yml, I get "python3: can't open file 'example.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

When I call 'example.py inputfile.yml', I get the following: "example.py: command not found."

example.py is discoverable using 'which'

Additionally, I have checked and confirmed that that file is chmod 774

Comment: @user3883001 I know exactly why it isn't working for you, and in fact I reproduced the problem.  I updated my answer to describe the problem and how to fix it.  Look at the bottom of the answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to do this on Unix systems (including Linux) is to make the Python file executable, and put the proper Python path in the first line as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

(or whatever the proper path is for your Python installation - use `which python3` to check).

Make sure the file is executable.  Then you can just invoke it directly from the command line:

```
example.py inputfile.yml
```

Python 3 will be automatically invoked based on the path given in the first line of the `.py` file.

As tdelaney pointed out, you can alterntively use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

if you want to pick up `python3` from the user's path rather than giving the path explicitly.  Whether or not that's preferable depends on your needs.

But from your comment, it sounds like the error message is complaining about `python3\r` not being found.  That means the line ends in a return character (`\r`, i.e. `^M`).  That strongly suggests it's a DOS file.  DOS files use a pair of characters to end line, `\r\n`.  Just convert it to a non-DOS file so that the line ends in `\n`, with no `\r` character.  That will solve your problem.

Comment: The file has #!/usr/bin/env python3 already set.  The files are 774'd.

Comment: 774 is intended.  We have fairly strict group permissions and I only need in-group users to be able to run this code.

I did as you suggested and changed permissions to 755.  Error is now "/usr/bin/env: 'python3\r' No such file or directory

Comment: @user3883001 Based on the error message shown in your comment, I know exactly why it isn't working for you.  See the last paragraph of my updated answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To run the script, python needs to find it (its on the PATH, so you are good there), it needs to be executable (774 is good for user and group) and linux needs to know how to execute it. Linux will peek at the top of the file looking for several different things including the "shebang". If the top of the file looks like

```
#!somepath someparams
```

linux will try to execute a program at somepath with someparams and the path of the script. So,

```
#/bin/sh
```

runs a program with your system shell.

```
#/usr/bin/python3
```

Runs a program with the python at that location. You can use the `env` program to decouple the program from an absolute path. With this, `env` will search the path for the first thing called "python3" and use it. Exactly where `env` resides is up for debate. Its usually in /bin and /usr/bin.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

or

```
#/bin/env python3
```